# Picture won't show when loading it into a UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've been using this code and it's working fine:

```
NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: currentMovie.trailerThumb]];        
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_moviesScroll addSubview:button];
```

Now I'm trying to load the pictures using AFNetworking like this:

```
UIImageView *testMe = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
[testMe setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentMovie.trailerThumb] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeHolder.png"]];        
[button setBackgroundImage:testMe.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_moviesScroll addSubview:button];
```

I get the place holder image fine but the original picture won't show.

I tried doing something like this:
I connected an outlet to an imageView in the IB and added this code:

```
[_test setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.url.com/pic.png"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeHolder.png"]];
```

The image will show fine. But if i'll do this:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:_test.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Again, just the place holder will show.

Comment: "coco" is the programming language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a commit one of the users added [here](http://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/822).
With that commit it's simple as

```
[button setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: currentMovie.trailerThumb] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeHolder.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: updated to: 
`[button setImageForState:UIControlStateNormal withURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentMovie.trailerThumb] placeholderImage: @"placeHolder.png"]]; `

Comment: tried `[_button.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL]];` , but not working

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
NSURL * photoUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.url.com/pic.png"];

                NSURLRequest*request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:photoUrl];

                __weak typeof(UIImageView) *weak_testImage = _testImage;



                [_testImage setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeHolder.png"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

                    weak_testImage.image = image;

                    [button setBackgroundImage:_testImage.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];



                } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {



                }];
```

Comment: why don't you name your variables `ololo1` and `ololo2` instead?

Comment: LOL!! I ended up using a commit one of the users added : https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/822 With that commit it's simple as `[button setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: currentMovie.trailerThumb] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeHolder.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: Just make sure setImageWithURL doesn't use a synchronous query, or else your app will block until the image is loaded.